# Facebook JS SDK not posting comments on timeline

Tags: facebook

I am using below code to implement facebook comment box on my site pages :

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com/test/public/story/read-searched-story?story=rRDMpYpeHA22aFm4OFahuV50iFqswqjzFzl7BJPbnyo=" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

When i am posting comment it asks to publish on facebook and when i click on post nothing happens either on my wall or activity log. any help will be appreciated..!!

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot found that facebook crawler needs some ogtags to crawl all pages mentioned on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/website/ and you can check your URL on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/.